# How to match a pipe to a category in a form-group

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore, angular-pipe

I'm trying to filter products by typing in a word into the search bar and if the categories form property matches the search term then limit the products to only that category.

I can add all the product into the the value param but I'm getting an error back saying cannot read property of 'starts' with of undefined

console logs

[image: console logs]

Custom pipe:

```
if(cName===""){
  return value;
}
else{
  console.log("Value : ",value)
  console.log("cName : ",cName)
const categoryArray:any[]=[];
for(let i=0;i<=value.length;i++){
  let categoryName:string=value[i].category;
  console.log("value i . category ", value[i].category)
  let cName: string = value[i].name;
  if(categoryName.startsWith(cName)){
    categoryArray.push(value[i])
  }
}
return categoryArray;
```

}
}

HTML:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchCategory">
</div>
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let p of products | async |category:searchCategory" [routerLink]="[p.id]">
  <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
    <img [src]="p.img">
  </ion-thumbnail>
  <ion-label>
    {{ p.name }}
    <p>{{ p.price | currency:'USD' }}</p>
  </ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

ts:

```
products: Observable<any>;
searchCategory:string="";
```

and ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.products = this.productService.getAllProducts();
console.log("all products", this.products);
}
```

EDIT:
After removing empty entries for categories as suggested by Shubham Bhokare I'm getting new errors in the console:

[console logs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZNgN5.png)

Comment: You have attached the same error log image as above. Please provide another error log.

Answer (score 0):

You have some empty entries for a category as **""**.

Hence this statement `let categoryName:string=value[i].category` is storing **categoryName** as **undefined** because there's no value in `value[i].category`.

This check condition `if(categoryName.startsWith(cName))` is failing due to above issue.

Handle undefined values by doing `if(categoryName && categoryName.startsWith(cName))`.

Comment: Okay, I removed the empty entries for category in firebase and made the change to handle undefined.Now the errors are showing 'Cannot read property 'category' of undefined. In the console log its printing out the product categories but not filtering

Comment: @cononor96, Your for loop is creating error now, it should be `for(let i=0;i<value.length;i++)`. Remove '='.